# Start java application in invisible mode

Tags: java, user-interface

Depending on a command line argument or virtual machine argument I'd like my application to start in an **invisible mode**. It does the same things in both cases, except that in invisible mode it simply doesn't display anything.

I can make the main program window invisible using `JFrame.setVisible(false)`. However, then I have to find every place in the code, where for example a warning message pop-up is opened etc. (there are a lot of those!).

Is there a more general way to do that? May-be something like the headless mode (which of course throws `HeadlessExceptions` which is not what I want).

Thanks!

Comment: Did you split your business logic with your display logic?
If so it should be simple to add some flags to not activate the display logic.

Comment: Don't create the JFrame in the first place, then you don't need to make it invisible.

Comment: You're right, I'll have to decouple view and logic better. So I guess there is no such configuration property?!

Comment: To run in a not-quite-headless mode? No. Esp if you use pop-ups as the system would expect results from them, which would never happen.

Comment: Now for some horrid "solutions", that you really should not use. You could switch Swing/AWT out for CHARVA and pipe standard out to dev null. Or you could (if on Linux) create a virtual frame buffer and throw your UI on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does your applications architecture look like? If it is cleanly separated then create a new View layer that does nothing.

If it is tangled up together, the best option would be to un-tangle it and then create a new view layer that does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    boolean gui = true;
    for (String s : args){
        if (s.equals("--nogui")){
            // Do not create GUI
            gui = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (gui){
        // Create the gui
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your presentation layer is tightly coupled with business logic you will have to do check in all your forms, and other visible classes. You should decouple your application, and than it would be as easy as calling one method.

In other case... well you will have a bunch of `if else if`.